# Outlining stat_summary2d bins in ggplot2()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to somehow outline the bins that contain data in a `stat_summary_2d()` plot.

For example, I have the following data:

```
my.test = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
                     y = c(1,2,3),
                     z = c(1,2,3))
```

And I plot it as follows:

```
p.test <- ggplot(data = my.test,
                 aes(x = x,
                     y = y,
                     z = z)) +
  stat_summary2d(breaks = list(x = seq(-.5,3.5,1),
                                y = seq(0.5,3.5,1)))  +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "z", 
                       high = "red", 
                       mid = "grey",
                       low = "blue",
                       midpoint = 2,
                       breaks = seq(0,3,1),
                       limits = c(0,4),
                       guide = "colourbar")
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

This is OK. But, sometimes, I prefer a nice white midpoint and I like to plot stuff on a white background for publications:

```
p.test2 <- p.test +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "z", 
                       high = "red", 
                       mid = "white",
                       low = "blue",
                       midpoint = 2,
                       breaks = seq(0,3,1),
                       limits = c(0,4),
                       guide = "colourbar")

ggsave(file = file.path("ptest2.png"),
       plot = p.test2 + theme_bw(base_size = 8),
       width=3, height=2, dpi=150)
```

And so I end up with this:

[image]

… and my data are invisible.

**My question:** Is there a way to add a thin, colored line around the boxes that `stat_summary2d()` generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as using the `colour =` argument. Remember in ggplot2, `colour` is for lines and points, `fill` is for, well, fill. The line thickness is set by the `size` argument.

```
p.test <- ggplot(data = my.test, aes(x = x, y = y,z = z)) +
  stat_summary2d(colour = "black", #size = 0.5,
                 breaks = list(x = seq(-.5,3.5,1),
                               y = seq(0.5,3.5,1)))  +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "z", 
                       high = "red", 
                       mid = "white",
                       low = "blue",
                       midpoint = 2,
                       breaks = seq(0,3,1),
                       limits = c(0,4),
                       guide = "colourbar") + 
  theme_bw()
p.test
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. If anyone else needs this, you can also change the line thickness using the `size = ` argument to `scale_fill_gradient()`.